# Timing Issue - How to Prevent Initial Loading of Non-essential Images and Videos in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, image, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension aimed at preventing the initial load of non-essential images and videos to conserve bandwidth and resources. The extension is intended to swap src attributes with data-src for lazy loading, but despite implementation, all media are fetched as per network monitoring, although they appear hidden on the webpage.

The script is executed at document_start, yet it seems the intervention occurs too late or does not effectively block the media from being fetched, only hiding them after the fact. I'm seeking advice on strategies or APIs that could enhance the extension's ability to prevent these initial loads more efficiently.

Could there be a more effective approach or specific Chrome APIs that I'm missing that could help achieve this goal better? Any insights or suggestions on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) Try removing the element first, maybe the browser will cancel the request. 2) Alternatively, use declarativeNetRequest to block all sub-resources by default, then your content script would send a message with the urls to unblock and onMessage listener would call chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateSessionRules with `tabId:sender.tab.id` and `priority:2` to override the default rules.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice on using declarativeNetRequest—it worked great for managing resource loading more efficiently! I'm now exploring how to handle Base64 embedded images, which are a bit trickier due to their instant loading. Any suggestions on how to preempt their rendering to conserve processing power? I'm also wondering if intervening before they render is viable or worth the effort for the sake of saving processing power. Appreciate your insights!

Comment: Normally such images are small icons, so hiding them would be detrimental to usability of the site.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for sharing this insight!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that I would recommend to consider working on such extensions:

1. Technical issue: Your extension cannot access the document's DOM tree before the browser creates a list of resources (for example, images) that need to be loaded. This means that the browser will most likely remember the `src` of images that were initially in the DOM and will start downloading them before your extension gets control. Therefore, your attempt to replace them will only load the second set of images (your images), which is even worse from a performance perspective.
2. Strategical: Your extension cannot know in which order some specific website wants to load images to function properly. Some websites must load certain images first to look right, while others are `waiting` (using the `onload` event, for example) to load certain images before doing everything else. Your extension will break this process because it will change image loading prioritization and may delay crucial resource loading, which in turn will delay the [First Contentful Paint](https://web.dev/articles/fcp), which is bad for SEO and user experience.
3. Strategical: The only way to intrude into the HTML document loading/parsing pipeline is to take the Chromium engine, for example, create your callbacks that will intercept the document after the browser receives it but before it is parsed, and create your own browser based on it, which is probably too much, taking into account N2 above.

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed feedback! I've managed to address the timing issue by utilizing declarativeNetRequest API to effectively manage resource loading. However, I'm still exploring solutions for embedded Base64 images. Do you have any advice on handling these efficiently, or should they not be a primary concern in terms of performance?